# Django - delete records with same many to many associations

Tags: django, duplicates, many-to-many

I have two models:

```
class DjProfile(DateTimeModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    ...

class Track(models.Model):
    all_producers = models.ManyToManyField(DjProfile)
    all_remixers = models.ManyToManyField(DjProfile)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True)
    track_link = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

I have many records of `Track` with same `title`, same values for `all_producers` and same values for `all_remixers` but different `track_link`. I'd like to keep only one record of those, regardless of `track_link` value, that may vary.

I might loop over all the records of `Track`, but I've a pretty large tables (like 2M records) and I'm afraid about performance. What is the best way to approach this problem?